# Understanding evaluation order in recursive scala countChange function

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a function that counts the number of ways to count change given an amount of money and a list of coins. This function appears to pass basic unit tests but if I am being completely honest, I don't fully understand why it works.

```
  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {

    def countChangeRec(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
      if (money == 0) 1
      else if(money > 0 && coins.nonEmpty) {
        countChangeRec(money - coins.head, coins) +
          countChangeRec(money, coins.tail)
      }
      else 0
    }

    if(money == 0 || coins.isEmpty) 0
    else countChangeRec(money, coins)
  }
```

Taking a basic example with arguments `money = 4` and `coins = List(1, 2)`

I currently come up with the following evaluation order to return 2 (which is not correct).

1. `countChangeRec(4-1, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
2. `countChangeRec(3-1, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4-2, List(2))`
3. `countChangeRec(2-1, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(2-2, List(2))`
4. 

```
countChangeRec(1-1, List(1, 2)) // => 1 returns 1 since money = 0 
          + countChangeRec(0, List(2)) // => 1 since money = 0
```

5. returns 2 // this is not the case since the functional actually returns 3.

Comment: This line: `countChangeRec(0, List(2)) // => 1 since money = 0` is wrong, check the code definition again and remember values are immutable.

Comment: I don't understand - I am passing 2-2 as a parameter and I had already passed `coins.tail => List(2)` as the second parameter?

Comment: Let me rephrase myself better, you are not properly expanding all the cases. You always have just two sums when you should have more.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the evaluation as follows (the order doesn't actually matter, this being a pure function) using the evaluation order is to expand the left-most function application and evaluate integer additions:

- `countChangeRec(4, List(1, 2))`
- `countChangeRec(3, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `countChangeRec(2, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `countChangeRec(1, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `countChangeRec(0, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(1, List(2)) + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + countChangeRec(1, List(2)) + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + countChangeRec(-1, List(2)) + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + 0 + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + countChangeRec(0, List(2)) + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `1 + 1 + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + 0 + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(3, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(1, List(2)) + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(-1, List(2)) + countChangeRec(1, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + 0 + countChangeRec(1, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(1, Nil) + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + 0 + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(3, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + 0 + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(4, List(2))`
- `2 + countChangeRec(2, List(2)) + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `2 + countChangeRec(0, List(2)) + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `2 + 1 + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `3 + countChangeRec(2, Nil) + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `3 + 0 + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `3 + countChangeRec(4, Nil)`
- `3 + 0`
- `3`

each application of a function uses, effectively, its own copy of the arguments it's been passed.

This evaluation order is very similar to Scala's.  The only difference is that this effectively evaluates function arguments in parallel, while in Scala it would be something like:

- `countChangeRec(4, List(1, 2))`
- `countChangeRec(4-List(1, 2).head, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(1, 2).tail)`
- `countChangeRec(4-1, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(1, 2).tail)`
- `countChangeRec(3, List(1, 2)) + countChangeRec(4, List(1, 2).tail)`

and so forth... so technically my evaluation strategy would correspond to

```
def countChangeRec(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int =
  if (money == 0) 1
  else if (money > 0 && coins.nonEmpty) {
    val minusHead = money - coins.head
    val tail = coins.tail
    countChangeRec(minusHead, coins) + countChangeRec(money, tail)
  } else 0
```

with the observation that since there's no dependency between `minusHead` and `tail`, we can evaluate them in parallel.

One important thing to know is that if an expression has no side effects (e.g. mutating a `var` or mutable structure, performing I/O, going into an infinite loop, or throwing an exception (this covers the 5 broad categories of impurity in Scala)), any strategy for evaluation which is compatible with data dependencies gives the same result.  This includes parallelizing the evaluation (which includes offloading evaluation to a different computer), and caching results.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I had a bit of a brain malfunction here not understanding that a bit of a tree of recursive calls is constructed starting from the first call of `countChangeRec(minusHead, coins) + countChangeRec(money, tail)`. I am a bit discouraged as I don't think I would have come up with this solution left to own devices but I suppose I will begin to see patterns and when (and how) to use recursion.

Comment: As for how one could come up with this, the basic idea to come up with a recursive algorithm is to come up with simpler sub-problems and a means of combining the answers to the simpler subproblems.  In this particular problem, you can divide the ways to make change into two categories, those that have at least 1 of the first coin and those that don't.  Since all we want is a total count and there's no double counting, that means that the combiner is just `+`.

Comment: For every way that has at least one of the first coin, that means we can remove a "first coin" and be left with a way to make `money - coins.head` from the coins, so that would be `countChangeRec(money - coins.head, coins)` ways.  If we're not using the first coin, then that corresponds to `countChangeRec(money, coins.tail)`.  Then it's just reasoning about base cases.